# How can I get the value from a schema in MongoDB

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, dictionary

I want to get the value from id I tryed this code

```
c = dict["ids"]["id"]
print(c)


{'_id': ObjectId('6070965b28721d6e49c58c74'), 
 'gu_id': 'STRING', 
 'ids': [{'id': 'STRING'}, {'xp': INT}, {'msg': INT}, {'date': INT}]
}
```

But I always get a error

Comment: What exactly do you want to retrieve ? `ids` is an ARRAY, you can't access it with a string, but rather an index `dict['ids'][0]['id']`

Answer (score 0):

i write this query at robo3t. Try it your computer.

[image: try this]